# Understanding definition of Interior (in topology of $\mathbb{R}$)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

- *Definiton.* The interior of a set is the union of all its open subsets.

  I tried an equivalent definition:
- Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. $X^o$ is an iterior set of $X$ if for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $A_n\subseteq X$ is open and $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_{n}$ is open.

**Can you check may last comment in this paragraph? And can you give an equivalent definition of interior?**

Comment: Your comment says that if $X^0$ is an interior set of $X$, then all subsets of $X^0$ are open. That is of course wrong, since all open sets except the empty set contain itself a closed set. If they wouldn't, then all those sets would have to be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these $A_n$ arbitrary open subsets of $X$? In what relations are the $A_n$ to $X^o$?
Without answering these questions, your definition of interior is without value.

Let me give you another definition of interior:

$X^o$ is the interior of $X$ if

- Every open $A\subset X$ satisfies $A\subset X^o$.
- $X^o$ is open
- $X^o\subset X$.